# Java GraphQL - Pass field values to resolver for objects

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I am looking to pass a field value to a resolved field using another object type.

Another way to put it if I have `Customer > User > Profile' - how can I pass the CustomerID field value that would be in customer to Profile as an argument or variable in order to resolve correctly?

Comment: There is no code, or other information about what you're using. I haven't used any GraphQL library for Java so YMMV but normally you'd attach this information to the values you return for each resolution point. When you get a `User` from a `Customer` it should carry some (or all) data from the `Customer` and likewise to `Profile`, so (naively) you'd probably do something `((Profile)resolveParams.getSource()).getUser().getCustomer().getId()`

Answer (score 22):

There's exactly 5 possibilities (as of graphql-java v12) to provide info to a resolver (`DataFetcher`) at any level:

**1) Directly pass them in the query (possibly on multiple levels):**

```
{customer(id: 3) {
      user {
         profile(id: 3) {
             name
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**2) Get values from the *source* object**

The *source* is the result of the enclosing query.
In your case, the source for the `customer` query is the root (whatever you provided at the query execution time, e.g.

```
graphQL.execute(ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
    .query(query)
    .root(root)
    .build())
```

The source for the `user` query is whatever `customer` query returned, presumably some `Customer` instance.
The source for the `profile` query is whatever the `user` query returned, presumably a `User` instance.
You can get a hold of the source via `DataFetchingEnvironment#getSource()`. So, if `User` contains the `CustomerID` you're after, just get it via `((User) env.getSource()).getCustomerId()`. If not, consider wrapping the result into an object that would contain all you need in the sub-queries.

**3) Pass the values around using the shared context**

graphql-java passes around an instance of `GraphQLContext` available to all resolvers. So, inside the `DataFetcher` for `customer`, you can store the `CustomerID` into it:

```
Customer customer = getCustomer();
GraphQLContext context = env.getContext();
context.put("CustomerID", customer.getId());
```

Later on, inside the `DataFetcher` for `profile`, you can get it from the context:

```
String customerId = env.getContext().get("CustomerID");
```

To initialize a context, pass it when executing the query:

```
ExecutionInput input = ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput()
  .query(operation)
  .graphQLContext(new HashMap<>())
  .build()
graphQL.execute(query, input);
```

This way is stateful, thus the hardest to manage, so use it only if all else fails.

**4) Directly get the arguments passed to a parent field**

```
ExecutionStepInfo stepInfo = dataFetchingEnvironment.getExecutionStepInfo();
stepInfo.getParent().getArguments(); // get the parent arguments
```

**5) Pass the values around using the *local* context**

Instead of returning the result directly, wrap it into a `DataFetcherResult`. That way you can also attach any object as a `localContext` that will be available to all child `DataFetcher`s via `DataFetchingEnvironment#getLocalContext()`

Comment: Thank you very much!
Could you please add the information about some use cases for using one or another way?
And which way is more preferable among all of them?

Comment: @Max If you can naturally express the value as a property of the parent, #2 is the easiest. If not, and the value is simple (no deserialization needed),  #4 is good. Barring those, #5 is good.  #1 and #3 are less preferable.