# Filtering nested fields, or mapping types to queries

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-spqr

Excuse the probably-basic question. I've used GraphQL SPQR to implement a fetch of a product DTO like so:

```
@GraphQLQuery(name = "products")
public Page<ProductEntity> getProducts(@GraphQLArgument(name = "count", defaultValue = "10") int count, @GraphQLArgument(name = "offset") int offset) {
    Pageable queryPage = PageRequest.of(offset, count);
    return productRepository.findAll(queryPage);
}
```

Note that I'm paging through my data repository with this query.

My DTO's are set up in a way that I can query as follows:

```
products(count: 10, offset: 0) {
    store {
        products /* attempting to query using the count and offset parameters here is invalid*/ {
            productName
        }
    }
}
```

Under the second type (store), I am again fetching a list of products. How can I tell GraphQL to fetch the second, nested list of products in the same way that it would fetch the first list of products?

I'm imagining the ability to bind the `GraphQLQuery` to my `ProductEntityDAO` class or something like this, so that fetches against that type can all resolve in the same way.

Your assistance is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Thanks Kaqqao. The solution worked perfectly, and I had the requirement to solve this for the general case of "An entity that has products".

To do that, I defined an Interface on my product entity that looks as follows:

```
@GraphQLInterface(name = "hasProducts", implementationAutoDiscovery = true)
public interface ProductEdge {
    Collection<ProductEntity> getProducts();
}
```

I then make my entity that has a connection to a list of products fetch it in a generalized way by implementing this interface on my entities that need to do this:

```
public class CommercialPartnerEntity implements ProductEntity.ProductEdge
```

And in my repository:

```
@Query("select child from CommercialPartnerEntity p inner join p.products child where p = :parent")
@GraphQLQuery(name = "relatedProducts")
Page<ProductEntity> findBy(@Param("parent") ProductEntity.ProductEdge parent, Pageable pageable);
```

Allowing me to, in my service, do things like this:

```
@GraphQLQuery(name = "productsList")
public Page<ProductEntity> getProducts(@GraphQLContext ProductEntity.ProductEdge hasProductsEntity, @GraphQLArgument(name = "count", defaultValue = "10") int count, @GraphQLArgument(name = "offset") int offset) {
    Pageable queryPage = PageRequest.of(offset, count);
    return productRepository.findBy(hasProductsEntity, queryPage);
}
```

And accordingly I have defined my resolver for any specific type in a generalized way. Would love to hear other people's thoughts on the solution.

When implementing things like "filter by name" I imagine this will come in very useful, too.

Comment: After some investigation, it seems I should be extending the functionality of the Spring data repository. Will update the question if it works out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you right, you're looking for a way to call an external method to resolve `store.products`. If that's the case, this is easy to achieve using `@GraphQLContext`.

You could e.g. do something like:

```
//Any class with queries
public class ProductService {

    @GraphQLQuery(name = "products")
    public Page<ProductEntity> getProducts(@GraphQLContext Store store, @GraphQLArgument(name = "count", defaultValue = "10") int count, @GraphQLArgument(name = "offset") int offset) {
        //your logic here, maybe delegating to the existing getProducts method
    }
}
```

If `Store` already has `getProducts`, you might want to `@GraphQLIgnore` it, but not mandatory.

If you're asking how to get the same arguments passed to `products` inside `store.products`, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159753/java-graphql-pass-field-values-to-resolver-for-objects/44179252#44179252). You can inject `ResolutionEnvironment` using `@GraphQLEnvironment ResolutionEnvironment`, and from there you can obtain `DataFetchingEnvironment` if you need it.

Comment: Thanks. I've built off your answer a little bit too, see updated question.