# How can I propagate graphQL query argument to child dataFetchers using graphQL java

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-java-tools

I am using those GraphQL Java dependencies:

```
|  +- com.graphql-java:graphql-java:jar:17.3:compile
|  |  +- com.graphql-java:java-dataloader:jar:3.1.0:compile
```

With this schema:

```
schema {
    query: Query
}

type Query {
    users: UsersNamespace
}


type UsersNamespace {

    userByPhone(phone: String!): User!
}

type User {
    id: String!
    photoId: String
}
```

Using this query

```
{
  user1: userByPhone(phone: "375290201111") {
      id
      photoId
  }
  user2: userByPhone(phone: "375290202222") {
      id
      photoId
  }
}
```

Assume I have a separate `dataFetcehr` for the User itself and the `photoId` which I get from a different source.

I want to pass the `phone` argument (or even the alias of the parent user) down to the `photoId` data fetcher.

I can not save the information on the `GraphQlContext` since the resolution is not performed "Depth-first", meaning the data fetchers will be called in this order:

1. `Users` data fetcher for `user1`
2. `Users` data fetcher for `user2`
3. `photoId` data fetcher for `user1`
4. `photoId` data fetcher for `user2`

So anything I will save for `user1` will be overridden by `user` data-fetcher.

How can I pass down arguments / information to child resolvers under the same alias?

*Note: `photoId` is always resolved only within a `User`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java GraphQL - Pass field values to resolver for objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159753/java-graphql-pass-field-values-to-resolver-for-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `ExecutionStepInfo` like so:

```
environment.getExecutionStepInfo()
      .getParent()
      .getArgument("phone").toString()
```